# How to pass a returning NSMutableArray from a method into a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I would like to know how to call a method from a NSObjectClass that returns a NSMutableArray and save that returning MutableArray into a NSMutableArray in the calling class.

effectively this is how it looks

NSObject class has the method with the return value

```
- (NSMutableArray *)myMethod {
  // do some stuff

  return myMutableArray
}
```

The class that calls this method dose all of the initialization so I can use the myMethod method but what I am uncertian of is how to get the returning myMutableArray into a MutableArray in this class...

is it something like

```
TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass *myObjClass = [[TheNameOfTheObjectClass alloc] init];
anotherMutableArray = [myObjClass myMethod];
```

because thats what I am trying at the moment and I am getting a warning

Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *__strong' from 'TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass *'

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think more info is needed. Can you add the interface for `TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass` (elide unreferenced methods) and the declaration of `anotherMutableArray`? ALso what do you mean by "into a `NSMutableArray`"? Do you wish to copy the returned array or just reference it?

Comment: You are going to have to post more code, are you using ARC?  How are these two NSMutableArray's defined?

Comment: I think your first step should be to learn programming, specifically the concepts of pointers, objects, and imperative programs.

Comment: all I need to know is how to call the method so the returning value is put into the object...

Comment: As written, the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How is `anotherMutableArray` declared?

Comment: @Chuck **NSMutableArray *anotherMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];**

Comment: @HotLicks if you looked at the code example of mine you would see I know how to return a value by the decliration of my method return type and the use of the return function in my method. **- (this is the return type *)methodname {** then in the fuction you use **return myMethodthatisOfTypeReturnType** lol. maybe it was you who fell asleep and dreampt that I did.

Comment: You're instantiating an array only to immediately assign *a different instance* to the variable, losing the original instantiation, that is a leak (non-ARC) or pointless (ARC).   And it still doesn't make the question any clearer.  Show the line of code that generates that error message (and the declaration of all types on the line).

Comment: Well, you have the assignment you need in your post above (though you shouldn't be initializing anotherMutableArray as you are a few comments up).  So what's your problem??

Comment: @HotLicks how do you pass the returning MutableArray from the method into the MutablerArray I just made.. That is what I am wanting to know.. Its just I am not to sure what to do here...

Comment: You need to understand the difference between an object and a pointer.  Also likely you need to understand the difference between a value and a variable/parameter.

Comment: @bbum I am using ARC, Effectivly I am getting a bunch of data from a server request, I am then using the NSObject Class to parse the data into their correct types for instance NSNumbers, BOOLS and NSStrings as currently everything is NSData. I then save the data into a NSMutableArray of Dictionaries that I am returning. The last thing I need to do is pass the returning value into a NSMUtableArray I can use.

Why is this not the correct thing to do?

Comment: @HotLicks I understand the difference between all those things.

Comment: Show us the line that produces this message:  Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *__strong' from 'TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass *'  So far you haven't done this.

Comment: @HotLicks that happens on this line **anotherMutableArray = [myObjClass myMethod];**

Comment: BS.  myMethod returns an NSMutableArray.  (At least according to what you've claimed above.)  The error message says you're assigning a TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass pointer to an NSMutableArray pointer.  Where is it that you're doing that??

Comment: And don't use "myObjClass" for the name of an instance!

Comment: yes I know its just an example.

Comment: That appears to be the issue;  in your efforts to create "just an example" for SO question purposes, you lost the critical pieces of signal that would allow us to efficiently answer your question.  Best to copy/paste the code directly, if at all possible.

Comment: yea.. sorry I was just trying to keep it simple because I use alot of weird keywords that relate to the data I am calling so it probably would have made even less sense.. I have learnt my leasson though so will do that next time for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a method like the following on a class called `Baginator`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) mutableDoggyBags;
```

And you want to call that method then:

```
Baginator *b = [Baginator new];
NSMutableArray *bags;

bags = [b mutableDoggyBags];
```

Parsing the question, it sounds like the equivalent of `mutableDoggyBags` is declared to return something other than a mutable array.

Specifically, if this line is producing an error on the assignment:

```
anotherMutableArray = [myObjClass myMethod];
```

Then, the following must be true:

```
• `myMethod` is not returning the same type as the type of `anotherMutableArray`.
```

In your case, it sounds like `myMethod` is declared as returning an instance of `TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass`. I.e.:

```
- (TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass*) myMethod;
```

Comment: I have solved it you are correct initally it was returning TheNameOfTheNSObjectClass, I closed the app opened it then cleaned it with the clean build and it worked!!! WTF